# Excluding records from a list

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm relatively new to using SQL but I'm totally stuck with what I'm doing.

I've got a list of codes which I don't want to have included in my data but I want to be able to exclude anything for the whole day if this code is appearing in any of the records for that patient on that day.

What I'm trying is only excluding the record which I have in the list not the full days record.

I'm sure this is simple but I've gone a bit brain dead.

Comment: Could you provide a brief description of the tables you're using. Is it a single table with CODE, PATIENT, DATE, other-info

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking (as you are short on detail such as what RDBMS you are using, what data type you are storing your dates in):

1. You will need to be able to determine whether two records are from the same date. How you do this will depend on the RDBMS and data type.
2. You can use either a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or a `NOT EXISTS` operator to identify records meeting your criteria:

`LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT r1.your_field...
FROM your_table r1 LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table r2
  ON r1.id_field != r2.id_field AND r1.date = r2.date AND
  r2.code_field = 'forbidden value'
WHERE r1.code_field != 'forbidden value' AND r2.code_field IS NULL;
```

This attempts, for every record in `your_table`, to find another record in the table with the forbidden value. By specifying that the code_field is null, such records are excluded.

`NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT r1.your_field...
FROM your_table r1
WHERE r1.code != 'forbidden value' AND
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM your_table r2
    WHERE r1.date = r2.date AND r2.code = 'forbidden value');
```

This, for each value, scans the table for a forbidden value and excludes rows where it finds a hit. This method is less efficient, and may be prohibitive if your data set is especially large, but is generally more understandable and may work for your application.

Answer (score 0):

This approach may get what you need:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyTable t
WHERE
NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        MyTable t2
    WHERE
        t2.PatientID = t.PatientID
        AND t2.LogDate = t.LogDate
        AND EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable t3
                WHERE 
                    t3.PatientID = t2.PatientID
                    AND t2.LogDate = t3.LogDate
                    AND t3.BadCode IN (867,5309)
                )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is a different approach using a CTE:

```
WITH BadPatientDates AS (
SELECT
    PatientID,
    LogDate
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE 
    BadCode IN (867,5309)
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyTable t
WHERE
NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 
FROM 
    BadPatientDates b
WHERE
    t.PatientID = b.PatientID
    AND t.LogDate = b.LogDate
);
```